# Creating arduino library linking question

Tags: c++

I know how to create my own arduino library and use it. I am using Xcode to create a c++ project. I have the arduino library files(Servo, Wire, Keypad, etc). If I want to include the Servo.h library file in my created library, how do I go about linking that? For some reason, I can't just add the Servo.h/.cpp files in my project because then I get other linking file problems that Servo.h references and are not linked in my project. Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't speak for Xcode, but in general with Arduino IDEs (UECIDE excepting) if you use a library within another library, that library also has to be #included in the main sketch.  That is the only way most IDEs determine which libraries need to be compiled into the finished program.

That's one of the first targets I had for UECIDE - to enable fully recursive library compilation.  Any libraries found within the master header of a library will also be included for compilation - and any found in those libraries, etc.  It took a lot of work (and it's by no means 100% perfect), which is why so few others do it and leave it up to the programmer to ensure the inclusion of the right sub-libraries in their sketch.

Comment: Yea, I guess I was just asking in general not necessarily with Xcode. If I were using Visual Studios, is there anyway I can use the current arduino library files (h/cpp) in my own library I am creating to be able to compile it before using? If I add, for example, Servo.h to my library it does not compile as there are other files Servo.h links to that I do not. Just seeing if there is an easy way to add other library files to my project to be able to compile.

Comment: No, it takes an intelligent IDE that properly understands the concept of the Arduino library to do that.  If the libraries were all pre-compiled code as .a files you'd still need to manually add all the -l... flags to the linker command, so it's not something that's unique to the Arduinosphere.  We just have a different way of telling the IDE what libraries need including (#include) than "normal" systems (which would equate to -lservo -lkeyboard etc)

Comment: Believe I have accomplished what I wanted to do. Using the VS Visual Micro plugin.